# Why does r aggregate summation deliver wrong result if dot is used in the formula argument?

Tags: r, aggregate

So I am encountering the following issue:

```
df = data.frame(...) # with columns "Article" & "Revenue"
df_agg = aggregate(.~ Article, data = df, sum)
# Let A be some Article
sum_1 = sum(df$Revenue[df$Article == A], na.rm=T)
sum_2 = sum(df_agg$Revenue[df_agg$Article == A], na.rm=T)
```

I would expect `sum_1 == sum_2` is true, but this is not the case. Why could that be?
The problem vanishes if I am not using the dot in the formula argument but instead `Revenue ~ Article`. But why?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. You can use the builtin `mtcars` or create your own data.

Comment: Why should it be the same? ```.~ Article``` means all columns not already in the formula aggregated on Article, whereas ```Revenue ~ Article``` means only Revenue.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck With mtcars I couldn't reproduce it. The sums were the same. I don't know which characteristics of my data causes this so I am askingyou if there is any reason you can think of, why these two sums could differ. I can't show you the real data.

Comment: Ah ok I got the issue.  I also had the column writeoffs which contained NA's. Because aggregate also skips the respective rows in the Revenue aggregation I ended up with a lower sum.